# Cant redirect www to non www via htaccess

Tags: linux, wordpress, redirect, http-redirect

i tried many way how to redirect www to non www, but nothing work.

This is currently my htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Website is working on non-www url with https. If i type to browser https://www.example.com it end in 404 error.

................................

Comment: Have you verified you can connect directly to `https://example.com/`?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've verified that the target URL `https://example.com/` is working when entered directly (if not that's a different problem that has nothing to do with redirection).

You might need to specify:

```
RewriteEngine on
```

in the .htaccess file before your directives, to activate the rewriting.

Also, the Apache server conf must be configured to have the [`rewrite_module`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) loaded (check via `apache2ctl -D DUMP_MODULES`), and to allow its use in your .htaccess file (via the [AllowOverride directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride)).